# Upgrade schema not running in one environment

Tags: magento2

This is a really odd one I haven't come across before and can't seem to find anyone else saying they have come across it either (no ticket with Magento I can find either).  In one environment only upgrade scripts are just not running were before they were running fine.  In all other environments they are running fine.

So the `setup_module` table reports a module version well behind what is in the codebase, but the site loads fine which it shouldn't - it should flag a mismatch in module version and prompt you to run `setup:upgrade` but it doesn't.  It's like Magento can't 'see' the new module version.  In fact, removing a relevant entry from `setup_module` makes no difference, equally commenting the upgrade schema code makes no difference.  No errors in the Magento or server logs, but all modules load and are reported by the `setup:upgrade` command.  Doesn't seem to make a difference in what the mode is, both developer and production mode shows the same issue.  Also worth noting that the same server runs another instance of the same site and all upgrades run fine there.  The codebase is also identical to other environments where upgrades are running fine.

I've cleared all caches including things like opcache.  Anyone come across this kind of oddity before?

Comment: Is there git setup with these, if yes can check the diff.

Comment: Yeah, no differences but actually just figured it out, someone has pointed the install at a different version of the database so it's simply that it wasn't pointing where it always had been before!